# Socket io sending duplicate messages after switching rooms

Tags: node.js, reactjs, websocket, socket.io

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEM1x.jpg)I am building a slack type application where there are multiple rooms for chatting. But if the click one room and send a message, it works fine, but after that, if go to another channel and send a message, my message gets to send 2 times, and again after switching 3 times, and so on (as in the picture)

**Here is the code**

selecting a channel
Client

```
const selectRoomHandler = (user) => {
  socket.emit("join__room", {
      room: user.userName,
  });
};
```

Server

```
socket.on("join__room", ({ room }) => {
    socket.leave(currRoom);
    socket.join(room);
    currRoom = room;
});
```

Sending messages to in channel
Client

```
socket.emit("room__message", {
  text: message,
  sender: userName,
  senderId: socket.id,
  room: selectUser.userName,
});
```

Server

```
socket.on("room__message", ({ text, sender, senderId, room }) => {
   io.in(room).emit("room__message__incoming", {
     text,
     sender,
     senderId,
     room,
     date: new Date(),
    });
});
```

Recieving messages on client side

```
  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("room__message__incoming", (data) => {
      if (data.senderId !== socket.id)
        setRoomMessage((prev) => [...prev, data]);
    });
  }, [socket]);
```

Message should appear only once and no duplicates

Answer (score 0):

Using rooms provided by socket.io can be tricky.
Personaly when I use rooms for more operations I like to manage the room state on my own.

```
export interface ClientRooms {
    [clientId: string]: string //* roomName
}

const clientRooms = {} as ClientRooms;

//in the connection:
clientRooms[client.id] = roomName; //roomName is a random string
io.sockets.to(roomName).emit('my_emmit', 'data ...')
```

Then you just change the roomName of that object to switch rooms and emmit to that room.

```
clientRooms[client.id] = otherRoomName;
io.sockets.to/*or sockets.in to send response to the joining client*/(otherRoomName).emit('my_emmit', 'data ...')
```

Like this you can add and remove clients form the rooms as you wish.
I hope you find this answer helpful.